# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, wamp

I've been searching stack overflow and numerous other resources for about 4 hours attempting to find the solution that could adequately fit my problems. I have ran into numerous posts on here regarding my current state however none were able to suit my needs, that I've found at least.

I'm setting up a XAMPP server with port-forwarding enabled so that I can remotely access my website through other routers. I've ran into the error message that is in my title and I honestly can not figure out what the issue is, I've tried uninstalling my anti-virus and disabling all of my router & windows firewalls. I am not too experienced with setting up XAMPP servers (in regards to port-forwarding) at least so I've never run into a problem like this.

I apologize in advanced if this seems stupid to you, but any advice/support with someone more experienced in this field would be greatly appreciated.

When I attempt to connect to the MySQL server with my IP address (97.xx.xx.xx) I receive the message in the title, however of course if I attempt to connect with 127.0.0.1 it works. One number off of my real IP and it returns this:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Thank you.

Comment: its only going to accept local connections, unless you specifically allow external ones

Comment: @Dagon I am wanting to know the proper way to do this though.

Comment: you set the host in the user privileges

Comment: google "Enable mysql remote connections" ... consider a server restart after changes ... do the necessary GRANTS. Then `select user,host from mysql.user` ... keep in mind that the wildcard for host is '%' ... those sorts of things

Comment: It can take an hour or two to sort this nonsense out and most of us would rather not waste all our time for nothing

Comment: cool. I enabled mysql remote connections and now my router page is accessible from my own IP, not just 192.168.1.1 anymore.